# Pivot for an animation in Unity3D (4.3)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d

What I want to do:

When a unit lands after falling I want to give it a slight animation of being "squeezed" to the ground and then going back to normal. (Say a slime blob falls and lands, it would get squeezed a little)

Using Pivot "Top Left" on all my sprites the issue that when I scale the sprite in the animation it doesn't scale to the bottom but to the top. My current temporary workaorund is also translating the sprite downwards to counteract that and make it look slike the sprite is being squeezed to the floor. However, there should be some better solution that works with multiple spritesizes and so on.

One thing would be changing the pivot point for just this animation, or maybe a movement thats percentual since the scaling is too. How would I do these though?